# Default value of timeout for a YUI Ajax webservice call

Tags: ajax, yui

Does someone has idea on what is the default timeout for an AJAX call through YUI, e.g. if we do not mention any value as timeout then what would be the value.

Appreciate the help in advance.

Regards,

Vaibhav

Answer (score 1):

looking at YUI connection manager code, it seems that if there is no timeout property set in the callback, it will not abort the ajax call (so is left to the browser/network settings)

```
if(callback && callback.timeout){
        this._timeOut[o.tId] = window.setTimeout(function(){ oConn.abort(o, callback, true); }, callback.timeout);
}
```